# I am trying to add my data to database and this error showed up

Tags: c#, asp.net, model-view-controller

The model backing the 'DonorContext' context has changed since the database was created. Consider using Code First Migrations to update the database 
Where did I go wrong?

This is my controller

```
  public class RegisterController : Controller
{
    private DonorContext dc = new DonorContext();
    // GET: Register
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult Create(RegisterModel registerModel)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            dc.RegisterModel.Add(registerModel);
            dc.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Login","Account");
        }
        return View();
    }
}
```

This is my model

```
 public class RegisterModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

This is my DAL

```
 public class DonorContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<DonorModel> DonorModel { get; set; }
    public DbSet<RegisterModel> RegisterModel { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Try updating your EDMX model.

Answer (score 0):

This simply means that your model has become out of sync from the database, probably if you looked at the database you would probably see that there is a difference in the columns or something like this.

By default Entity framework will just report this as an error, but you can change this behaviour.

As it suggests you can switch on code first migrations [(see here for process)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn579398(v=vs.113).aspx), the advantage to this, is that you can use the **Update-Database** command (in the package manager console) to update the database schema.

It is also possible to get this to run automatically whenever your application runs, but I would recommend caution when dealing with Database schema. You ideally want to ensure your model is exactly the way you want it before you make changes in the DB

Answer (score 0):

> The model backing the 'DonorContext' context has changed since the
>   database was created. Consider using Code First Migrations to update
>   the database

If you used Code-First Migration

And previously you implement and model like

```
public class RegisterModel
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

And now you changed the model means by changing any property datatype or adding any property as your need like

```
public class RegisterModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

Here i changed property "Id" datatype from string to int

Then the above error occurred while you run you project

**Question:** Why this above error comes?

**Answer:** 
In simple language,

In Entity Framework Code-First Migration, you always saw the "_MigrationHistory" table in database so this table contains all the entries that you made while you enabling migrations to your project.
If you change any model property or datatype then those models are mismatch with entries in "_MigrationHistory" table
So the entity framework throws an exception and as a result above error comes.

Again

**Question:** How can i get rid from this error?

**Answer:** Just open package manager console and type "update-database -verbose" and hit Enter key.

Note: -verbose gives you all your changes details on console that you made now.
Be sure before this, the data loss may happen.

Comment: @Sam, Please check answer, If it helps, then vote up and accept answer :)

Comment: @Sam, Is the answer helps you? let me know